# Can't use string I imported from excel spreadsheet as equality variable in Python, openpyxl

Tags: python, excel, openpyxl

I imported a cell value using `openpyxl`. The excel cell is in `B2` and it is a simple word, let's say it is `testing`, without the quotation marks.

I import it, then assign it to a variable:

```
cell = worksheet.cell('B2')
variable = str(cell.value)
```

If I print variable, I'll get:

```
"testing"
```

With the quotation marks.

I'm trying to use it in an if statement like this:

```
if cell == "testing":
    print("working")
```

But nothing happens. I have tried:

```
print(cell == "testing")
```

And I get `False` in return.

How can I fix it?

When I import the cell, it is an object from the package, but I convert it to string using the `str()`. The cell originally (on the spreadsheet) has no quotation marks around it, but after I import it does and I can't get rid of it. I tried to use `.replace()`, `.strip()`.

Comment: I guess cell is not a `str` type, try `print cell`.... use `str(cell.value)` instead

Comment: I was gonna guess the same thing.  It looks like there's a separate cell object, though the openpyxl documentation isn't very well organized.  http://openpyxl.readthedocs.org/en/latest/tutorial.html#saving-to-a-file

Comment: Tried to use str(cell.value) still not working.

Comment: Not a permanent solution that's why I'm only including in the comment, but for the time being use single quotation marks outside the double quotation mark. `print(cell == '"testing"') >> True`.

Comment: if you got variable printed as `"testing"`, I guess it would be `variable = '"testing"'` as @Leb saied

Comment: I tried that, still getting False. Really weird.

Comment: update your code and error message in the post

Comment: data_only=True only affects cells with formulae. That would appear to have nothing to do with this question.

Answer (score 1):

Cells contain more than just a value which is why when comparing them with a value will always be `False`. You test should be `if cell.value == "testing"`. There is no need to explicitly convert to a string, this is handled by the library.

Answer (score 0):

Set `data_only=True` when loading the workbook:

```
wb = load_workbook("scm.xlsx", data_only=True)
```

as per OP @Filipe Barreto Peixoto Teles' own prior edit to the question.